# How make a viewmodel return data to another?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to find a solution to passing back data from a viewmodel to another when I call DoClose()

I've got a view where the user can add informations in edittext, there is also a button that open a new view where the user can enter others informations. Then he need to go back (`DoClose()`) to the first view and there click on the button to save informations.

I tried to make a `RequestNavigate<>` but it create a new view in stack.

I don't know how can I get back the informations from the second view.
Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article from @gshackles gives one mechanism for doing this - http://www.gregshackles.com/2012/11/returning-results-from-view-models-in-mvvmcross/