# Pass information between related viewmodels (List and Filter)

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

ViewModels:

AnimalsViewModel - contains a list of animals
AnimalsFilterViewModel - a list with selectable animal types (Birds, Mamals, Fish, etc)

AnimalsViewModel launches the filter viewmodel *ShowsViewModel(AnimalsFilterViewModel)* so you can select what Animals you want to be listed.
How to pass back the selected filter (animals categoies) to the AnimalsViewModel? Using MvxMessage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How make a viewmodel return data to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952101/how-make-a-viewmodel-return-data-to-another)