# How to pass data back in when closing a view

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a ViewModel that has a command that opens another view:

```
public ICommand OpenAnotherViewCommand
{
    get 
    {
        return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<AnotherViewModel>());
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Then in `AnotherViewModel` I want to be able to go back to the first view model. Originally I did something like this:

```
public ICommand ReturnCommand
{
    get
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // Add some stuff from this model to pass to the first view model

        return new MvxCommand(() => {
            ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>(parameters);
        }
     }
 }
```

I added an `InitFromBundle` to my first view model and this worked too. However, then I realized that my original first view model still existed (I noticed this because of some event handlers that seemed to be firing multiple times!). My `ShowViewModel` created an new `FirstViewModel`, but the old one was never destroyed (it seems really obvious now). So the stack of views is now `first -> another -> first` when it ought to be just `first`.

So after face palming over that I replaced my `ShowViewModel` in `ReturnCommand` with `Close(this)` and now I've fixed the navigation problem and I'm not producing a long line of unneeded view models. However, what I've lost is the ability to pass back data from `AnotherViewModel` to the first one.

So how can I pass data back to my first view model when the second one is closed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How make a viewmodel return data to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952101/how-make-a-viewmodel-return-data-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

As you may already know you can always use a form of variable in your view models which is accessible from another view model. For instance using a static variable. However, imo it's not a good practice specially when you are going to repeat this pattern across your application.

## 2

In your case I think you can benefit from [MvvmCross Messenger plugin](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Messenger/). Look at N=9 at [MvvmCross N+1](http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/) for more information on the implementation. A sample source code is also available [here](https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-09-Location%20And%20Message).

By using the messenger plugin then it's easy. You simply publish a message before closing down the child view. The parent view has already subscribed to receive that kind of message and the rest should be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks. I think that helps a lot. I had basically done #1, but after watching the video, I think it might make sense to rejigger it to use the messenger.